# How to fix No adapter attached; skipping layout in android pie

Tags: java, android

When i am parsing data via volley recyclerview work just fine below android pie but i get  No adapter attached; skipping layout in android pie version.

In my fragment in onCreateView

```
    recyclerView= view.findViewById(R.id.vaccine_recycler);

    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext()));
```

With in the volley jsonobject request

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager=getFragmentManager();
                                    VaccineAdapter adapter= new VaccineAdapter(getActivity(),vaccineInfoList,fragmentManager);
                                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And my Adapter is given below

```
    public class VaccineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<VaccineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        Context context;
        List<VaccineInfo> modelList;
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
        FragmentManager fragmentManager;

        public VaccineAdapter(Context context, List<VaccineInfo> modelList, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            this.context = context;
            this.modelList = modelList;
            this.fragmentManager = fragmentManager;
            layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);

        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.vaccine_row,viewGroup,false);
            return new ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {

        }





        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return modelList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
           .......

            }
        }
    }
```

Here goes my error message E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout.

Comment: Are you sure that the error message appears after you set the adapter to the RecyclerView? Because until you receive the response from the server, you have a RecyclerView with no adapter. I would recommend setting the adapter in the onCreateView, and enable the adapter to update its data (rather than passing them in the constructor)

Comment: apparently, i found out the problem was in my data parsing, the actual error was D/parseError: java.io.IOException: Cleartext HTTP traffic to * not permitted. Adding android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" in my manifest solved the error